# Help understanding table in SAM E54 Datasheet

Tags: datasheet, atmel, eeprom

I apologize if this isn't the right place to ask this question, but I'm having trouble interpreting a table in the [SAM E54 datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/60001507E.pdf).

I am trying to configure the size of the SmartEEPROM on an SAME54 Xplained board. The example project from Atmel Start states:

```
/* This example assumes SBLK = 1 and PSZ = 3, thus total size is 4096 bytes */
```

So I looked in the datasheet which says, the SmartEEPROM interface maximum size depends on SEESTAT.PSZ and SEESTAT.SBLK:
[image]

I can't figure out which column corresponds to which configuration bit. It would seem the column on the left is SEESTAT.PSZ, but then it wouldn't make sense for SEESTAT.SBLK to be 3 according to the chart.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the columns of your table are the actual page size, rather than the value from the SEESTAT.PSZ register field. The page size is determined from the PSZ value according to a table a couple pages after the one you asked about:

[image]

The rows are then the values from the SEESTAT.SBLK register field.